# Show Css animation when hover over mouse

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to show an animation of drawing an angled and straight line and to show my text from left to right when hovering over a button and I am fairly new at this. also is there a way for my text to stay and not go away after animation finishes?

Here is my code, the code is a combination of other answers from stack overflow.

```css
.skew {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  animation: draw 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: drawLine 0.7s linear;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.showText {
  animation: showText 2s;
  position: relative;
  top: -17px;
  left: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes showText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes drawLine {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="menubtn">hover over me</button>
</div>
<div class="skew">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="showText">menu item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for this, you need to do a javscript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add/toggle a class on the `div.skew` element with Javascript, and define `animation` rules on that class or children of elements with that class, like so:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button.menubtn"); //Select the button
var skewElement = document.querySelector("div.skew"); //Select the 'skew' element

button.onmouseover = function(){
  skewElement.classList.toggle("startAnimation");
}
```

```css
.skew {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.skew.startAnimation {
  animation: draw 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.startAnimation .line {
  animation: drawLine 0.7s linear;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.showText {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -17px;
  left: 15px;
}

.startAnimation .showText {
  animation: showText 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes drawLine {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="menubtn">hover over me</button>
</div>
<div class="skew">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="showText">menu item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to have the text visible even after animation's end, you have to specify `animation-fill-mode: forwards` on `.showText`, like I have done in the snippet above.

Comment: @FarnazDaneshvar If this solved your problem, do consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking on the arrow button below the votes for this answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**To get the animation done on hovering, first we have to create an event for hovering for that particular element using javascript**

*Then call a function when that event is triggered , for you it will be displaying some animations*

*Just for simplicity , i just made a parent div for your entire animation elements , and not displaying initially*

*Later on hovering , we change the css display property of that parent element to `block` which will display all of your animated elements*

*Also to make sure your text stays after animation , there is an animation property called `forwards` which will keep your final animation state for the later time*

```js
var hvrbtn=document.getElementById("hvrbtn");
hvrbtn.onmouseover=()=>{
var anim=document.getElementById("anim");
anim.style.display="block";
};
```

```css
.animated{
display:none;
}
.skew {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  animation: draw 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: drawLine 0.7s linear;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.showText {
  animation: showText 2s forwards;
  position: relative;
  top: -17px;
  left: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes showText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes drawLine {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="menubtn" id="hvrbtn">hover over me</button>
</div>
<div class="animated" id="anim">
<div class="skew">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="showText">menu item</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```